# Error de sintaxis en expresión regular

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer

Paso por acá porque después de estar 1 día entero buscando en google, no logré dar con la causa.

Estoy intentando validar un campo (Importe estimado : decimal), con REGEX en javascript y probé de las siguientes maneras:

```
var decimalValidation = /^\d+(\.\d{1,4})?$/gis;

var decimalValidation = new RegExp('^\d+(\.\d{1,4})?$','gis');
```

La cuestión es que en el primer caso dice que "no puse el ;" cuando es claro que si... y el segundo caso me muestra "Error de sintaxis en expresión regular".

Nota: Esto solo ocurre en Internet Explorer 5 (Internet Explorer 11, pero como tienen un legacy usan modo de compatibilidad), ahorrando preguntas, debo mantenerlo sinó se rompen varias cosas por la compatibilidad.

¿sabrán decirme como puedo hacer que funcione esa expresión regular?

EDIT
Acabo de testear con:

```
var decimalValidation = new RegExp('^\d+(\.\d{1,4})?$','gim');
```

y no funcionó (reemplace la s por la m).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el primer caso: es claro que sí tiene el `;`, pero ¿y las comillas?

Comment: disculpa, pero cuales comillas? no tiene comillas

Comment: creo que ya di con la causa, pruebo y notifico. Acabo de notar que en la porcion de código que compartí primero aquí en stackoverflow, no me ilumina la letra "s" de gis ni el ;, viendo que podía venir por ese lado intenté reemplazando la s por la m. Vi que lo reconoció tanto en regex101 como en stack. Como podría redactar correctamente la respuesta? no quiero arriesgarme a decir que fue por un problema de letra...

Answer (score 0):

Auto respondo a mi pregunta:

Reemplacé la "**s**", de **gis**

```
var decimalValidation = /^\d+(\.\d{1,4})?$/gis;
```

por una **m**

```
var decimalValidation = /^\d+(\.\d{1,4})?$/gim;
```

y el formato que ven, en lugar de usar una instancia de RegExp.

Se evidencia funcionamiento:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como ya viste, `s` no está implementado en IE. Ver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/dotAll. Pero además no tiene *ningún* sentido que uses `g` (múltiples coincidencias), `i` (no diferencia minúsculas/mayúsculas) o `m` (multilínea) con este regex. `/^\d+(\.\d{1,4})?$/` sin modificadores es lo correcto en este caso.